# How to customize admin sales order grid collection?

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I have to add a custom where clause to the query that retrieve data to fill sales order in the relative admin grid.
I know that it is defined here `\vendor\magento\module-sales\etc\di.xml` as virtualType

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

and `\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider.php` is used to retrieve data, but where and how could i use `_initSelect()` or `_renderFiltersBefore()` discussed here [How to join order grid collection to custom table in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/how-to-join-order-grid-collection-to-custom-table-in-magneto2) to change query?

In magento 1 i did it with the `filter_condition_callback` option for `addColumn()` in customized grid file.

Comment: in brief you want to add custom column in sales order grid ??

Comment: no, i want to add a where clause. this is the original query `SELECT main_table.* FROM sales_order_grid AS main_table`, i have to change it to `SELECT main_table.* FROM sales_order_grid AS main_table WHERE .........`

Comment: @MohammadMujassam i think you are also here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1650 :)

Comment: it's incredible that from yesterday i try to find how to do this simple things that for m1 was very ease.

Comment: yes I did achieved that but I had to add one custom column in sales_order_grid table, that was pretty easy, your case is bit different I believe ?
but if its just matter of one or two column, I would recommend you to add you custom column in sales_order_grid, because every day no of sales will be added & running query for that will impact on performance ....

Comment: i don't want to add any custom columns, i want simply to filter by customer_group WITHOUT add customer_group column/filter in grid. How could i obtain it? They remove `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` event that maybe was the right way, so what replace event's dispatch?

Comment: Hey Luca, did you get any solution?

Comment: @LucaS did u find a solution to this ?

Comment: @ReenaParekh nope, isn't this answer usefull https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91807/how-to-join-order-grid-collection-to-custom-table-in-magento2?

Comment: @piyush_systematix read my answer, maybe it could help you

Comment: @ReenaParekh read my answer, maybe it could help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a plugin on `Magento/Framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/Reporting` and its `search()` method.

Just create `di.xml` in your custom module `Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting">
        <plugin name="sales_grid_collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order\Grid"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and plugin

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Sales\Order;

class Grid {

    public static $table = 'sales_order_grid';


    /**
     *
     */
    public function afterSearch($intercepter, $collection) {

        if ($collection->getMainTable() === $collection->getConnection()->getTableName(self::$table)) {      

            // retrieve where clause
            $where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE);

            // ...
            // works with $where
            // ...

            // set the new where clause    
            $collection->getSelect()->setPart(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE, $where);                

        }

        return $collection;

    }

}
```