# Show only Specific Order Status by user in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, admin-user

I need to show only pending order by users I follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36102/restrict-order-grid-to-specific-status-for-user)

They used `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` in magento 1, what exact event in magento 2

and

How to Collect only pending Orders from Order collection and Show for specific users.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/110483/36463  what is the exact place do you need to add this logic? the same event available in m2 in vendor/magento/module-sales-archive/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113308/how-to-customize-admin-sales-order-grid-collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I achieved this Solution via Plugin.

**di.xml:**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
      <plugin name="sales_order_pending" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomSalesOrderGridCollection" sortOrder="100" />
</type>
```

**CustomSalesOrderGridCollection.php**

```
          <?php namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

    class CustomSalesOrderGridCollection
    {
        private $messageManager;
        private $collection;
        protected  $adminSession;
        protected $logger;

        public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
            SalesOrderGridCollection $collection,
            \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        ) {

            $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
            $this->collection = $collection;
            $this->adminSession = $adminSession;
            $this->logger = $logger;
        }

        public function aroundGetReport(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
            \Closure $proceed,
            $requestName
        ) {
           $current_adminuser =   $this->adminSession->getUser()->getAclRole();
           $this->logger->addDebug("admin user");
           $this->logger->addDebug($current_adminuser);

           if(12 == $current_adminuser){

             $result = $proceed($requestName);
             if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
                 if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {

                     $this->collection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending')));
                 }

             }
           }
            return $this->collection;
        }
    }
```

After Clear Cache and Login that user, then its will show only pending Order in `sale_order_grid`.

Comment: It's working well, but in content->pages grid page page_id column_id not found error showing, when i disable the plugin the content->pages loading without any error

Comment: Getting error in customer grid, cms page and all module. because it will run in all collection grid.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue and finally I resolved the issue by following code. You can use following code with your customisation.

First you need to create a plugin.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
      <plugin name="sales_order_grid_collection" type="VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin\CustomSalesOrderGridCollection" sortOrder="100" />
     </type>
```

Create plugin file in `VENDOR/MODULE/plugin/CustomSalesOrderGridCollection.php`

**CustomSalesOrderGridCollection.php**

```
<?php namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface as MessageManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as SalesOrderGridCollection;

class CustomSalesOrderGridCollection
{
    private $messageManager;
    private $collection;
    protected  $adminSession;

    public function __construct(MessageManager $messageManager,
        SalesOrderGridCollection $collection,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession
    ) {

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->collection = $collection;
        $this->adminSession = $adminSession;            
    }

    public function aroundGetReport(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $requestName
    ) {
        $result = $proceed($requestName);
        if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
             $current_adminuser =   $this->adminSession->getUser()->getAclRole();
             if(12 == $current_adminuser){
                  if ($result instanceof $this->collection) {
                      $this->collection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => array('pending')));
                  }
              }
             return $this->collection;
        }
        return $result;

    }
}
```